# Introducing EhCache broke web app (no error message)

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat7, ehcache

This question is similar to the one posted previously on SO:

[Ehcache causing Tomcat 7 to give 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23475934/ehcache-causing-tomcat-7-to-give-404/23504048#23504048)

However, by following the two changes suggested, the problem is still there:

1. Make sure ehcache.xml is in WEB-INF/classes
2. Make sure that Tomcat is of 7.0.52 or later

(I am running Tomcat 7.0.69)

The webapp simply did not start when I introduced EhCache into it.  There
were no error messages.

In `catalina.log`, it simply said that

```
Jan 26, 2017 5:34:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will 
be found in the appropriate container log file
Jan 26, 2017 5:34:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/myWebApp] startup failed due to previous errors
```

And in my webapp's own log, I could only see that a listener `MyListener`
simply said the context was initialized and then it was also immediately
destroyed.  There were no indication as to what caused the immediate destroy action.

```
2017-01-26 17:34:48,242  [op-2]  INFO MyListener,localhost-startStop-2:62 
- contextInitialized(): creating hibernate session factory
2017-01-26 17:34:49,437  [op-2]  INFO MyListener,localhost-startStop-2:138 
- contextDestroyed(): shutting down Quartz scheduler
```

The webapp could start in my development environment (in Eclipse) but refused to start in a deployed environment (run on tomcat).

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the problem was that I forgot to check-in an updated version of `hibernate.cfg.xml`.  The deployed environment missed this file so the webapp could not start.

What made this bug hard to track down was there there were no error messages at all.  Only after my colleague told me that she also could not start the webapp (in her Eclipse environment) with this error message I realized that I forgot to check in `hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException: 
Second-level cache is used in the application, but property 
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given, please 
either disable second level cache or set correct region 
factory class name to property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class 
(and make sure the second level cache provider, hibernate-infinispan, for example, is available in the classpath).
       at org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCachingRegionFactory.buildEntityRegion(NoCachingRegionFactory.java:69)
       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:348)
       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1760)
```

In other words, for some reasons the error messages were printed in Eclipse but not tomcat.

I hope tomcat, hibernate, and/or ehcache could have spit out more meaningful error messages in the deployed environment.

By sharing this story I hope it can help someone fix a similar problem quicker in the future.